# Permutation of cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $\gamma \in \text{Sym}(G)$ such that $\gamma (1) = 1$ and $\gamma (gH) = \gamma (g)H$ for all $g\in G$ and $H\leq G$.

This means $\gamma$ induces a permutation of the left cosets of any subgroup of $G$.

> I need to show that $\gamma$ fixes any left coset of the Center $C(G)$ of $G$, that is $$\gamma(g)C(G) = gC(G)\,.$$

I tried some simple calculations which did not work. Now I think some more structural arguments are necessary. Any ideas?

Comment: HINT: Try to show that $\gamma(g)$ is conjugated to $g$.

Comment: Are you saying that the condition $\gamma(g)H=\gamma(gH)$ must hold for all subgroups $H<G$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Crostul Honestly I am not able to see that $\gamma (g)$ and $g$ are conjugated.

Comment: As $\gamma$ fixes all subgroups, for every element $g$ one gets that $\gamma(g)$ generates $\langle g\rangle$.

Comment: For what it's worth, the standard notation for the *center* of a group is $Z(G)$ (from German *zentrum*, I believe).  The notation $C(H) = C_G(H)$ is reserved for the *centralizer* of a subgroup.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a counterexample using $\textsf{GAP}$. The group is
$$
G \;=\; \mathbb{Z}_9 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_3 \;=\; \langle a,b \mid a^9=b^3=1,b^{-1}ab=a^4\rangle,
$$
with the function $\gamma\colon G\to G$ defined by
$$
\gamma\bigl(a^j b^k\bigr) \;=\; a^{-j} b^{-k}.
$$
According to $\textsf{GAP}$, this permutes the left cosets of each subgroup of $G$. Indeed, the proper, nontrivial subgroups of $G$ are

1. The cyclic subgroups $\langle a^3\rangle$, $\langle b\rangle$, $\langle a^3b\rangle$, and $\langle a^6b\rangle$ of order $3$,
2. The cyclic subgroups $\langle a\rangle$, $\langle ab\rangle$, and $\langle ab^2\rangle$ of order $9$, and
3. The subgroup $\langle a^3,b\rangle$ of order $9$,

so one could check this statement by hand without too much trouble.
However, the center of $G$ is  $\langle a^3\rangle = \{1,a^{-3},a^3\}$, so $\gamma$ switches the cosets $\{a,a^{-2},a^4\}$ and $\{a^{-1},a^{-4},a^2\}$.

---

Here are a few more observations and comments:

1. The statement is true if $\gamma$ is an automorphism of $G$.  For then $\gamma$ must fix every subgroup of $G$, so it is a [power automorphism](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/148954/automorphism-fixes-subgroups).  By a [result of C. Cooper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01110066?LI=true), it follows that $\gamma$ is central in the automorphism group, so by the argument at the end of Matt Samuel's (now deleted) post, it follows that $\gamma$ fixes all cosets of the center.
2. A bijection $\gamma$ between two groups satisfying the given conditions is known as a (normed) $\mathfrak{R}$-isomorphism. See Section 9.4 of [Schmidt, *Subgroup Lattices of Groups*](https://books.google.com/books?id=EuVadOnix5MC&pg=PA527). (The part on $\mathfrak{R}$-isomorphisms starts on [pg. 530](https://books.google.com/books?id=EuVadOnix5MC&pg=PA530).)

Comment: Of course, it would be nice to have an elementary argument that $\gamma$ preserves the left cosets of each subgroup of $G$, but I couldn't see an obvious one.  In case it helps anyone else prove this, the automorphisms of $G$ are generated by $(a,b) \mapsto (a^2,b)$, $(a,b)\mapsto (ab,b)$, and $(a,b) \mapsto (a,a^3b)$.

Comment: I have posted a question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358909/how-do-we-identify-mathfrakr-automorphisms-of-a-group) asking for an elementary proof.

Comment: Thanks for giving me closure. All those hours wasted trying to solve it!

Comment: Thank you very much. I could not find a counterexample so you helped a lot!